# How to create a function with a variable number of columns

Tags: monetdb

In my case, I would like to be able to send multiple columns to an (R) function, however the columns themselves are defined at run time.
Even worse, the calculation that has to be performed depends on the data of all columns. (So I cannot execute it per column)

In the documentation I only see examples with a fixed amount of parameters and they are all of a single data type.

Is it at all possible to have a flexible number of arguments?
I tried to use the following but that didn't work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION rapi01(i table) RETURNS DOUBLE LANGUAGE R {
    10;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is currently not supported.